# when and why use or equalto (|=) shorthand operator

Tags: java, operators

I was looking source code of a java project, herein i found an operator `|=` for boolean variables.
Can anybody tell me what exactly is this? and best way to use this.

Thanks for reply, now improving my question: what `|=` shorthand operator actually does. as per my test it shows:

```
false | true = true
false | false = false
true | false = true
true | true = true
```

But i still not clear, how it determines the result. And any use case where i can use this.
Thanks

Comment: it is known as `shorthand operator`

Comment: @Shams it's a logical OR, see my update.

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

`a |= b;` means the same as `a = a | b;`, in the same way that `a += b;` means the same as `a = a + b;`.

You would use it whenever you have something of the form `a = a | b;` (which is rare) and want to shorten it.

Answer (score 4):

As you have got your answer that it is a short and a compound assignment operator. So if you write

```
a1 |= a2;
```

or

```
a1 = a1 | a2;
```

the both mean the same thing. Its just the way to write the code.

Regarding the two W's which you have asked i.e, *when to use and why to use?* is completely dependent upon the programmer as some programmer finds the first one as more readable and some find the latter.

Here is a list of [other such operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm).

---

```
Operator   Description                                   Example
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|=        bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator   C |= 2 is same as C = C | 2
^=        bitwise exclusive OR and assignment operator   C ^= 2 is same as C = C ^ 2
&=        Bitwise AND assignment operator                C &= 2 is same as C = C & 2
<<=       Left shift AND assignment operator             C <<= 2 is same as C = C << 2
>>=       Right shift AND assignment operator            C >>= 2 is same as C = C >> 2  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a short form for an assignment doing a logic OR with the left-hand operand.

```
a|=b ---> a=a|b
```

You can do the same thing with other operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `&`, `^` , etc.

Update:

Adding something because it seems you need a short explanation of the logical or: This operator returns true only if at least one of its boolean operands is true. See this page on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).